# -Wconversion-null does not take all constructors into account

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gnu

Upgrading some legacy code, I've started getting "warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 1 of ‘Identifier::Identifier(int)’ [-Wconversion-null]" messages from g++.  Mostly this is good, but it doesn't seem to take classes with multiple constructors into account.

For example, take this test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Identifier
{
  private:
    int m_iID;

  public:
    Identifier(const char* p_c) { m_iID = p_c ? p_c[0] : 0; }
    Identifier(int i) { m_iID = i; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Identifier* p_ID = new Identifier(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

(Please ignore what the constructors actually do, this is just an illustration of the issue.   For context, the code in question is a class that stores an identifier in the form of a hash value.  The constructors can either take a string to convert to a hash, or the hash value directly.)

The "new" statement on the third to last line throws this warning.  The thing that is puzzling me is that g++ is apparently assuming that it needs to use the Identifier(int i) constructor, and ignores the Identifier(const char* p_c) constructor, which *is* a pointer.

Note that changing the ints to unsigned ints causes an ambiguity error instead, this being a 32-bit system.

I know specifying -Wno-conversion-null would fix the problem, as would passing 0 or explicitly casting NULL to const char*.  But I'm curious as to why the seemingly valid constructor is being ignored.  Plus, I'd like to avoid a massive search-and-replace job whilst keeping the warning active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on this CentOS box, NULL is defined in `linux/stddef.h`:

```
#undef NULL
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define NULL 0
#else
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#endif
```

As such, NULL in C++ *is* an integer; therefore the compiler chooses the `int` constructor by default and gives you the warning you're seeing.

Comment: But it's also a valid thing to set a pointer to (it's __null on my Xubuntu box here).

Comment: That's true, Subi211, which is *why* the compiler is warning you. You used `NULL` in your code, suggesting that you intended to use a pointer-related function, but the rules of C++ say that the `int` constructor is the one the compiler needs to choose. It's probably not what you intended, so the compiler warns you. `NULL` is assignable to pointers, but it's an `int` first.

Comment: @subi211 if c++11 is available to you, you can use nullptr instead of NULL.

Comment: @LukeB it's not (at least not in all cases).  In fact, it appears that it's gcc's preparations for C++11 that caused this for me in the first place.  :)

Comment: @RobKennedy You're right, it's just that there's a part of me that thinks that the compiler should be bright enough to check if there's an equivalent function taking a pointer.

Comment: To clarify, I mean that if C++11 is going to have a special value for NULL, nullptr, then surely it should assume that any use of it should use the pointer-related function rather than an integer-related one if there's a choice between the two of them available to it.